# Please rectify this jQuery script

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to close the menu overlay when i click outside the menu.

The script I used is:

```
jQuery('html').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.widget-area, .widget-area-visible').length === 0) {
        $('#secondary').hide();
    }
});
```

It is showing TypeError: $ is not a function

This is my test site: http://elysiumit.com/carinaenew/

Please help, I'm new to jQuery.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area widget-area-visible" role="complementary">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-slideoverlaymenu-container">
          <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
           <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-126"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-124"><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-125"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-123"><a href="#">Renewable Energy</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-122"><a href="#">Radio Solutions</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-120"><a href="#">Realtors and Property Development</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-282""><a href="#">Our Clients</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i have added a new .js file and called in the header

Answer (score 3):

Since `jQuery` works, but `$` doesn't for some reason, you can replace all instances of `$` with `jQuery`:

```
jQuery('html').click(function(event) {
  if (jQuery(event.target).closest('.widget-area, .widget-area-visible').length === 0) {
    jQuery('#secondary').hide();
  }
});
```

Or if you prefer using `$`, you can put the whole thing in an IIFE whose argument, `$`, points to jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $('html').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.widget-area, .widget-area-visible').length === 0) {
      $('#secondary').hide();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Once that's fixed, your `#secondary` looks to be properly hidden when there's a click outside of the menu:

```js
(($) => {
  $('html').click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.widget-area, .widget-area-visible').length === 0) {
      $('#secondary').hide();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#secondary {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area widget-area-visible" role="complementary">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-slideoverlaymenu-container">
      <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-126"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-124"><a href="#">Welcome</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-125"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-123"><a href="#">Renewable Energy</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-122"><a href="#">Radio Solutions</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-120"><a href="#">Realtors and Property Development</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-282"><a href="#">Our Clients</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
content outside of menu
```

Comment: Yes I tried now, and the script worked...but the whole menu is hidden. Something wrong with the script. please help

Comment: The jQuery included by WordPress [has 
 `jQuery.noconflict()` applied](https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/). Good answer.

Comment: @merryxian What menu are you referring to? Please post the HTML relevant to the problem

Comment: @CertainPerformance plz see the Question, I have added there.

Comment: @merryxian See edit - it seems to perform as expected. When there's a click outside of `#secondary`, `#secondary` disappears.

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
 $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.widget-area').toggleClass('widget-area-visible');
  $('.sidebar-toggle').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled');
  $('.sidebar-toggle').find('i').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
 });
 $('.sidebar-toggle-inside').click(function() {
  $('.widget-area').toggleClass('widget-area-visible');
 }); 
 
 $('body').click(function(event) {
  $('.widget-area').toggleClass('widget-area-visible');
  $('.sidebar-toggle').toggleClass('sidebar-toggled');
  $('.sidebar-toggle').find('i').toggleClass('fa-bars fa-times');
 }); 
});

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is the theme script now the menu overlay is working only when i click the body, button is not working. HTML of button is as follows: <div class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggled">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
   </div>

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is the url of my test site: 
http://elysiumit.com/carinaenew/ 
please help...

Answer (score 0):

By default when you enqueue jQuery in Wordpress you must use `jQuery`, and `$` is not used (this is for compatibility with other libraries).

Your solution of wrapping it in `function` will work fine, or you can load jQuery some other way (but that's probably not a good idea in Wordpress).

If you must use `document.ready`, you can actually pass `$` into the function call:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('html').click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('.widget-area, .widget-area-visible').length === 0){
     $('#secondary').hide();
   }
 });
});
```